# EditText black on black on a certain device

Tags: android, xsd, android-edittext

I have a really weird issue, on every device that I test my application the edittext behaves as you'd expect, the text is highlighted and it is black on a white background.

Specifically on Lenovo Yoga tablets when the edittext is focused the text will become black and blend in with the background.

[image]

The layout for this is:

```
 <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/ip_layout"
                android:layout_below="@id/display_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                    android:background="#8A8A8A"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="1dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" />
                <EditText
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
                    android:hint="@string/Hostname"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:id="@+id/host_address"
                    android:maxLength="50" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is happening because of background set in linearLayout, can you remove this line " android:background="#8A8A8A" "and check it how it works.

Comment: That linearlayout doesn't wrap the edittext it is only a 1 pixel spacer.

Comment: You should use a View to create some space...

Comment: yes, your parent view is a relativeLayout and inside that it has linearLayout which is having "width="match_parent". Either remove the linearLayout or background clolor of the layout.

Comment: You'll noticed that the linearlayout has height set to wrap content which has a padding of 1dp so they do not overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a problem on a particular device it may be due to the devices custom theme. Recent Android devices need to support the Holo theme and you can explicitly ask for that theme in your manifest using:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't test the fix (I don't have access to the tablet) but I'm going to guess that this is probably the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create your own nine patch image and use that as the background of your EditText otherwise befaviour of Edittext will chnage with device and version of android.

If you want to create more effects for edittext backgrounds like pressed, focused and default state then you need to create a selector for background image of edittext:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@android:drawable/Epressed"/> 
    <item 
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/Efocused"/>
    <item 
        android:drawable="@android:drawable/Edefault"/>
</selector>
```